# Integer Wrapper Class

Tags: java, integer

Integer Wrapper class

```
Integer obj = new Integer("1000");

System.out.println(obj.byteValue( )); //-24
```

I am not able to understand that how this output is formed. I want to understand how this "1000" in an integer is converted into "-24" in a byte. I want to know about the logic behind this.

Comment: Hint: (1) What is the range of byte numbers (how many bits they can hold)? (2) Take a look at binary representation of -24 and 1000.

Comment: @GauthamM Thank you sir now I'm able to understand it

Comment: Possibly related: [How are integers cast to bytes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting an integer to a byte will give the last 8 bits of of the integer.

1000 in decimal -> 1111101000 in binary

Converting this to a byte value gives you 11101000 which is -24.

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#byteValue()) say:

> Returns the value of this Integer as a byte after a narrowing primitive conversion.

which isn't particularly helpful if you don't know what a "narrowing primitive conversion" is. Well, you can look into the Java Language Specification ([section 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) for the definition of that:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T.

The `Integer` 1000 is represented by 32 bits:

```
00000000 00000000 00000011 11101000
```

`byte` is 8 bits, so we discard all but the 8 lowest order bits, we get:

```
11101000
```

which is -24 in 8-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary. -24 = -128 + 64 + 32 + 8