# type casting required on function calls taking short datatype variable as a parameter

Tags: java, primitive-types

Whenever I use byte or short data type as a method parameter, on method calls, I am required to explicitly cast the values I pass to those methods.

To better explain:

```java
void foo(short x)
{}
```

```java
void main() {foo((short)32);}
```

**If I dont use short here then warning is generated.**

```java
method foo in class px cannot be applied to given types
required: byte
found: int
```

How can I get it better?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java

Answer (score 4):

No way out.

Java doesn't have a way to code `byte` or `short` literals. Any number literal is an `int` value and converting an int to a short without casting always creates a warning.

Comment: so should i silently ignore these warning or should I perform explicit casting but casting as I learnt somewhere is expensive

Comment: @Marcos: you cannot ignore it because it's not a warning, it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

Integer literals implicitly have the type `int`, and converting from an `int` to `byte` or `short` potentially loses information, so it requires explicit casting.

So don't use `byte` or `short` unless you really need to, which is very rarely the case.

Comment: I was using short & byte so that I could efficiently manage the space... however I learnt somewhere that explicit casting has its own inefficiency problems.!?

Comment: @Marcos: wrong on both accounts (and badly premature optimization even if it were correct). The CPU only works with int or long anyway, so using short or byte is actually potentially *less* efficient. Casting is not a problem at all. The *only* case where using byte or short can make sense is in large arrays.