# Problems with casting and short parameters in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
public class A {
   private void doTask()  {    
      doInt(99);
   }   

   public short doInt(short s)  { 
      return 100;
   }   
}
```

The code gives a compiler error on line "doInt(99)".

```
The method doInt(short) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

Can someone explain why it's giving me the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5106766/269514, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2294934/269514

Comment: More recent duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16505959/269514

Answer (score 7):

In java, the default type of an integer number is an `int`. Java will automatically upcast (eg from `short` to `int`), but will issue a warning with downcasting (eg from `int` to `short`) because of possible loss of data.

The fix for your code is this:

```
doInt((short)99);
```

This explicit downcast changes the `99` (which is an `int`) to a `short`, so there's no (further) possible loss of data.

Comment: thanks very much. I am not seeing a warning. Actually it gives a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
public class A {
   private void doTask()  {    
      doInt((short)99);
   }   

   public short doInt(short s)  { 
      return (short)100;
   }   
}
```

Java thinks that all literals (such as 99 or 100) in your program is int.

If you pass big number, 12345678 for example, it will be cutted to fit to `short` value. Java cannot cut number without you, so you must do it yourself. That way you see that you casting int to short

Comment: Casting 100 to short is not necessary. When you assign a numeric literal to a short and when its value is within the legal range, the literal is assumed to be a short.

Comment: Yes, but I thought in earlier version of java you need to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast 99 to a short. Please try the following

```
public class A {
   private void doTask()  {    
      doInt((short) 99);
   }   

   public short doInt(short s)  { 
      return 100;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> int data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason.

And hence `99` is treated as an `int`.

Read more details on [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

You need explicit casting when required.
Change `doInt( 99 )` to `doInt( ( short ) 99 )` and it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of error is

**You cannot implicitly convert nonliteral numeric types of larger storage size to short**

So change your code to following.

```
public class A {
   private void doTask()  {    
      doInt((short)99);
   }   

   public short doInt(short s)  { 
      return (short)100;
   }   
}
```