# autoboxing of numeric literals : wrapper initialization vs passing method arguments inconsistency

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, primitive, autoboxing

Please consider 2 cases:

```
//1
Short s = 10; //obviously compiles    

//2
takeShort(10); //error - int is not applicable

//where:
static void takeShort(Short s) {}
```

I assume that case 1 is changed by compiler to :

```
short _temp_s = 10;
Short s = Short.valueOf(_temp_s);
```

Could you please explain what compiler is trying to do in case 2, so it does not compile ? If it is not trying to apply autoboxing as it does in case 1, then why ?

**EDIT**

Reference to JSL in johnchen902 answer explains compiler's behaviour.

Still not exactly clear why JLS does not support "A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion" for Method Invocation Conversion as it does in Assignment Conversion for the case of constant expression of type byte, short, char, or int.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Short s = 10;
```

This is an `Assignment Conversion`, and `10` is a constant expression. [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) said:

> ### 5.2. Assignment Conversion
>
> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is assigned to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> ......
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
> - - Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short.

---

```
takeShort(10);
```

This is a `Method Invocation Conversion`.  [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) said:

> ### 5.3. Method Invocation Conversion
>
> Method invocation conversion is applied to each argument value in a method or constructor invocation : the type of the argument expression must be converted to the type of the corresponding parameter.
>
> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion
> - a widening primitive conversion
> - a widening reference conversion
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.
>
> ......
>
> **If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the parameter by a conversion permitted in a method invocation context, then a compile-time error occurs.**

Unlike Assignment Conversion, non of conversion listed above can converts `int` to `Short`, so a compile-time error occurs.

<sub>Unfortunately some has rejected kiruwka's edit before I can approve it, so I edit it myself</sub>

The example of Method invocation conversion:

```
// takeInteger(int) takeDouble(double) takeObject(Object) takeIntegerObject(Integer)

takeInteger(5);  // an identity conversion
takeDouble(5);   // a widening primitive conversion
takeObject(new Integer(5)); // a widening reference conversion
takeIntegerObject(5);   // a boxing conversion
takeObject(5);   // a boxing conversion followed by widening reference conversion
takeInteger(new Integer(5)); // an unboxing conversion
takeDouble(new Integer(5)); // an unboxing conversion followed by a widening primitive conversion.
```

Comment: Perfect, man! JLS Method Invocation Conversion explains it all. I would like to give simple examples of MIC cases explained above appended to your answer.

Comment: I think you should revise your unboxing conversion examples: method should be having primitive type as declared parameter, i.e. `takeint` and `takedouble` instead of `takeInteger` and `takeDouble`

Comment: @kiruwka But that broke (my) naming conventions : [See here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 2):

The literals like `10` are `int` by default in Java. So, you are trying to assign `int` to a method which takes `Short` or `short` as a parameter, which would require explicit casting. You can assign `10` to a `short` variable, but you can't pass it as an argument to a method that accepts `Short` or `short`. You can cast it and pass it as follows:

```
takeShort((short)10);
```

**EDIT :**

The `int` has a range of `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, whereas `short` has a range of `-32768` to `32767`. Until and unless the value of the literal is within the range of `short`, it would be Okay for the compiler to convert it to `short`. But, as Boris the Spider mentioned in his comment, once the value of literal exceeds the range of `short`, it won't be able to convert the literal to `short`, since there would be data loss. Thus, compiler doesn't converts the literals to `short`, when passsed as an argument in a method.

Comment: yes, I understand that the method requires short(or Short) to compile. My questions is : why compiler could not do conversion by itself, like, for example it does when compiling: 
Short S2 = (int) 10;
short s2 = (int) 10;

Comment: @kiruwka because then what happens with I do `takeShort(Short.MAX_VALUE + 1)`?

Comment: @Boris the Spider I expect that compiler could do exactly same range check when initializing Short(or short) with compile-time constant, such as final int int_const = 10; Short S2 = int_const;

Comment: @kiruwka no because inputs to methods are not generally known at compile time. If I call `takeShort(x)` the compiler has no idea where `x` came from or its value.