# Why am I am getting an incompatible types error?

Tags: java

I'm learning java and creating some simple test programs with notes in them and I'm getting an error saying "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short" with short shortVal= val5 + val6; I'm looked and this error meaning I'm trying to put an int value into a short variable but the value I'm storing in the short is only 27, so I'm a bit confused as to what is wrong.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double val1=4;
        float val2=9;
        long val3=30;
        int val4= 8;
        short val5= 15;
        short val6=12;
        byte val7=20;
        short shortVal= val5 + val6; //why the error here?
    }
}
```

Comment: More exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919423/why-am-i-getting-a-warning-about-possible-loss-of-precision-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java

Comment: Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+incompatible+types%3A+possible+lossy+conversion+from+int+to+short) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `short + short` is, somewhat paradoxically, `int`. So you're trying to assign an `int` to a `short` variable (`shortVal`).

Answer (score 1):

`short` + `short` will result in an `int`. You need an `int` variable to store the result :

```
int shortVal = val5 + val6;
```