# Behaviour of short and int in java

Tags: java

I saw this one question in scjp preparation book.

```
public class Yikes {
    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("Long ");
    }
    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("Short ");
    }
    public static void go(int n) {
        System.out.println("int ");
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        short y = 6;
        long z = 7;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }
}
```

The output is `int Long`.

I am passing `short` datatype variable to overloaded method go. Now go has a `short` datatype version also. Then how come the one with `int` is getting invoked? What is the reason for this behaviour?

I am quite new in java. So please help me here.

Comment: `Short` and `short` are distinct types, many expressions get promoted to `int`.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java

Comment: Yep, if you used `short` rather than (the abomination) `Short` then you'd get the expected result.

Comment: my god...I just didn't notice. `short` and `Short`??? Gotta be aware of weird ways of java from now on.

Comment: Yep. [All the primitive types have corresponding objects for boxing.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#190697)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there is no method `go(short s)` to choose, Java has to choose another one. This can be done in two ways:

1. *Widening*, widening the `short` to an `int`
2. [*Autoboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), surrounding the `short` with a `Short`, the corresponding wrapper class.

Since *widening* has been around longer than *autoboxing* (introduced in Java 5), the JVM chooses this alternative first if available.

Therefore, the `go(int n)` method is invoked.

Comment: For further reference, [S5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#12687) of the JLS lists the order that conversions are considered when deciding which overload to call.

Comment: Are you sure the reason for precedence is just age? It makes sense since that way is backwards compatible.

Comment: Have to learn to read the java code more carefully now. `short` and `Short` two different datatypes !!

Comment: @Luis: Yes, they didn't want to change the way old code works, so they pretty much had to give widening higher priority.

Comment: but wait..There's `long z` variable which went to method with Long datatype as argument. Then why it didn't give compile error?

Comment: @Shades88: First it sees if it can widen the `long` to anything, which it can't. So, then it tries to autobox it, which succeeds. If you add a new method `go(double n)` the widening will succeed and this will be invoked instead of the `go(Long l)`.

Comment: @Shades88: Since you can't widen a `long` to either a `short` or an `int`, Java uses Autoboxing to *convert* from `long` to `Long`.