# Different implementations of compare method for Long, Integer and Short?

Tags: java, integer, compare, long-integer, short

Why are the implementations of the static method `compare` for `Long`, `Integer` and `Short` in Java's library different?

For `Long`:

```
public static int compare(long x, long y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

For `Integer`:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

For `Short`:

```
public static int compare(short x, short y) {
    return x - y;
}
```

Comment: Because the return type is `int` in all the cases.

Comment: Because `x - y` is simpler and works for `short`. Sure, it could do it the long way, like the others, but the simpler way is also faster, so it's a **better** implementation. `x - y` will not work for `int` and `long`, so they have to do it the ternary operator way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you try:

```
System.out.println(Long.MIN_VALUE - Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

or

```
System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

You will get `1` because of overflow(update: should be underflow here, as mentioned in another answer), which is incorrect.

However, with

```
System.out.println(Short.MIN_VALUE - Short.MAX_VALUE);
```

you will get correct value `-65535`, because `short` will be converted to `int` before `-` operation, which prevents the overflow.

Answer (score 4):

`x - y` is presumably the most efficient (since the alternative involves branching twice), so that's used for `short`.

But `x - y` can't be used for `int` or `long`, because this will [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) when the resulting value doesn't fit in an `int`, which can give a positive value when the result should be negative, or a negative value when the result should be positive (or zero in either case).

Note: when subtracting two `short`s, [the resulting value is of type `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477750/primitive-type-short-casting-in-java), so that can never overflow.

```
// long - long
System.out.println((int)(2147483649l - 1l)); // -2147483648, not 2147483648
// int - int
System.out.println(-2147483648 - 1);         // 2147483647, not -2147483649
// int - int
System.out.println(1 - -2147483648);         // -2147483647, not 2147483649
// short - short
short s1 = -32768, s2 = 1;
System.out.println(s1 - s2);                 // -32769, as desired
```

For what it's worth: the values above were chosen since they're roughly around the minimum and maximum values for `int` (and `short`), to demonstrate at which point it overflows.

Answer (score 2):

int can have values between `[-2147483648, +2147483647]`. If you subtract `-2147483648` from `+2147483647`, you will get `4294967295`. This can't be stored in an int, therefore we use this for comparing 2 ints

```
return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
```

The same is the case with long.